# Trigger js function from inside another in an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, dom-events, unobtrusive-javascript

```
var game = (function() {

    function start() {
        //somefunction
    }

    function save_count(someparamt) {
        //somefunction
    }

})();
```

How could I trigger `savecount()` from the browser url?
`javascript:savecount();` won't work and neither `game.savecount()` and neither `window.game.savecount();`

Comment: In your current example `game` is `undefined`. That is probably not what you intended.

Comment: The [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth) might help.

Comment: Can you accept an answer by clicking in the hollow checkmark?

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant to do this:

```
var game = {

    start:function() {
        //somefunction
    },
    save_count:function(someparamt) {
        //somefunction
    }

};
```

Yes, this *will* push the `game` object into global scope.